# Remove admin role from the “Author” user listing on individual post screen

Tags: author, list-authors

How to remove the admin role from the Author listing screen from the individual post?
Which hook to use to do this?
Can anybody help me? 
[image]

Check the above screen

Comment: This is not a role, but the authorship to be assigned to the post. Also, this field is visible to the admins and the editors only if not explicitly specified otherwise.

Comment: I did it but I need to pass array and I am stuck with it `$user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',"WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID<>1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID='".$selected_author_id[0]."'",$user_search->query_where);`...In place of $selected_author_id[0] I need to pass array but if I pass array its not giving any result can anyone help?

Comment: Please edit your question according to your comment and make clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my above Question

```
add_action('pre_user_query','ap_pre_user_query');
function ap_pre_user_query($user_search) {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ($user->ID!=1) { // Is not administrator, remove administrator (you can add any user-ID)
    global $wpdb;
    global $user_ID;
    //Fetch the custom field value added in user section
    $meta = get_user_meta( $user_ID );
    $selected_author_id = unserialize($meta['select_md'][0]);
    $count = count($selected_author_id);
    //to the data you got add the current user to it
    $selected_author_id[$count] = $user_ID;
    $store_ids = '';
    foreach($selected_author_id as $ids){
        $store_ids .= $ids.',';
    }
    $final_ids = rtrim($store_ids,',');
    //This query will return you the result you want
    $user_search->query_where = str_replace('WHERE 1=1',"WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID<>1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (".$final_ids.")",$user_search->query_where);
  }
}
```

Check the output below
[image]